# Availability of a function?

Tags: c, function

I just noticed that a function, which is passed as an argument in C, is no more available in the main function for direct calling. the compilation of the code below produces the error

```
"../main.c:22:8: error: called object ‘hello’ is not a function or function pointer"
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void hello(void)
{
    printf("hello there\n");
}

void main(hello)
{
    int y = 100;
    printf("%i",y);

    if (y==100)
        hello();
}
```

is it the case or I did something wrong?

EDIT: I changed the main call to - `void main(void hello (void))` Now there is no error in compilation but still the call to hello function after IF statement doesn't execute printf statement.

EDIT NO 2 : After reading many answer, I learnt that we can pass a pointer to a function as an argument to another function. passing whole function as argument is meaningless. Actually, this whole confusion arose out of the following opengl C code, which apparently ran successful in Eclipse IDE:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include<GL/gl.h>// Header File For The GLUT Library

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.4,0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei)h);   // indicates the shape of the available screen area into which the scene is mapped
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-10,10,-10,10,-10,10);


}

void display (void)
{
    int i,j;

    while(1){
    for (i=-10; i <=10; i++){
    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(i,2,5);
        glVertex3f(6,-i,-5);
        glVertex3f(1,9,-1);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();}
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop ();
    return 0;
}
```

Here if you notice the call glutDisplayFunc(display) APPARENTLY passes the display function as an argument.How this is happening?

Comment: Man! I don't get your point!! why would you pass a function into your main?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've managed to blur things horribly.

`void main(hello)` declares `main` (incorrectly) as returning nothing and taking a single argument of type `int` (implicit `int`).  You can't call an `int`; hence your local variable hides the external function of the same name.  The C89 and pre-standard C allowed the 'implicit `int`' notation; it is officially not allowed in C99 or C11, though many compilers will continue to allow it unless you ask them for warnings.

You should declare `main()` as either:

- `int main(void)`
- `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Windows does allow [`void main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336), sadly.  C++ does not.

If you use GCC, compile with options like `-Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration` (preferably with `-Werror`).  Not all versions of GCC support all those options; use those that your version does support.

Incidentally, by declaring `hello` as an argument to `main()`, you are hiding or shadowing the external definition of the `hello()` function.  This is standard C behaviour; a name defined at local scope hides different objects with the same name defined at outer scope levels.  You can use the `-Wshadow` option to GCC to spot when you run into this as a problem.

---

#### Post-Edit

As I already asked, why on earth do you think the startup environment is going to pass a pointer-to-function to your `main()`?

The function definition:

```
void main(void hello(void))
```

still does not match one of the acceptable patterns.

Further, the startup code won't pass a pointer to function to your `main()`; it will basically call your code as if you'd written `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (or possibly `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`).  You are guaranteed not to get a pointer-to-function passed to your `main()`.

So, whatever else happens, you will not be successful.  Typically, the value of `argc` (and perhaps part of `argv`) will be treated as a pointer to function (even though it isn't).  All hell will break loose.

Simply define:

```
int main(void)
```

and call `hello()` directly in the body of `main()`.  That's about all that makes sense.

---

For the record, this is what GCC says about the code in the question (as amended):

```
$ gcc -O3   -g   -I/Users/jleffler/inc   -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror   -Wshadow -c hello.c
hello.c:3:6: error: no previous prototype for ‘hello’ [-Werror=missing-prototypes]
 void hello(void)
      ^
hello.c:8:6: error: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Werror=main]
 void main(void hello (void))
      ^
hello.c:8:6: error: first argument of ‘main’ should be ‘int’ [-Werror=main]
hello.c:8:6: error: ‘main’ takes only zero or two arguments [-Werror=main]
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:8:16: error: declaration of ‘hello’ shadows a global declaration [-Werror=shadow]
 void main(void hello (void))
                ^
hello.c:3:6: error: shadowed declaration is here [-Werror=shadow]
 void hello(void)
      ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

---

#### Passing pointers to functions — the OpenGL code

You can pass a pointer-to-function as an argument to any function that expects such an argument.  However, `main()` is one of the functions you can't tinker with (the functions in the Standard C library should be treated as 'cannot be changed' either; ditto the operating system interfaces for the platform(s) you use).

In your OpenGL example code, it is perfectly legitimate to pass a function pointer like `display` or `reshape` to the `glutDisplayFunc()` and `glutReshapeFunc()` functions because they are designed to accept pointers to functions.  Had you written your initial offering as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void hello(void)
{
    printf("hello there\n");
}

static void invoke(void (*function)(void))
{
    printf("-->> %s:\n", __func__);
    function();  // Or (*function)();
    printf("<<-- %s\n", __func__);
}

int main(void)
{
    int y = 100;
    printf("%i\n", y);

    if (y == 100)
        invoke(hello);
    return 0;
}
```

there would have been no outcry from anyone — compiler or human.  This is clean (C99 or C11) code that helps in understanding pointers to functions.  If you write `void invoke(void function(void))` without the explicit pointer, the compiler automatically converts the type to 'pointer to function taking no arguments and returning no value — aka `void (*function)(void)`.  So, you can write that if you prefer, though I prefer the explicit pointer notation, not least because inside a function, or as a global variable, you must use the explicit pointer notation, so using that with function arguments is consistent.  Inside a function, writing:

```
void function(void);
```

declares a function, not a pointer to function variable; that must be written:

```
void (*function)(void) = hello;  // Note no parentheses on hello!
```

Similarly at with variables at file scope.  So, using the `void (*function)(void)` notation in function argument lists (in prototypes and definitions) is consistent with the rest of the language and is therefore the better notation to use.

Comment: whatever you write your main's declaration, the operating system's startup code still pass to main the parameters as `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. How can it know what function your program have and want to call? You'll end up using the parameter as a wrong type and can never run the program

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: yes, precisely, as I mentioned in my paragraph starting _Further, the startup code won't pass a pointer to your function…_

Answer (score 4):

The parameter `hello` shadows the global `hello`, so all appearances of `hello` within `main` refer to the parameter, not the function. And since the parameter is of type `int` (because you didn't specify a type and `int` is the default) and `int`s aren't functions (or function pointers), that's a type error.

Comment: alright. I changed the main call to - void main(void hello (void)) still the call to hello function after IF statement doesn't execute printf statement.

Comment: Why on earth do you think the startup environment is going to pass a pointer-to-function to your `main()`, @Saurabh?  It won't; it will basically call your code as if you'd written `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (or possibly `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`).  You are guaranteed not to get a pointer-to-function passed to your `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
main(hello)
```

is wrong

use

```
main()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, pre-standard C and C89 both allowed you to declare parameters with no type (and assumed that the type was `int`).  However, `main()` was always supposed to be defined as either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or other variations as allowed by the implementation.  It is (very, very) poor style to write such code in 2014; it was in 1999, too.  But it was allowed until the C99 standard was released.  Since then, strictly, it is not allowed by the current C standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with you, I just showed what was wrong with his code since this was the question